# How to get link for each menu item and them linked it on the page in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I created Menu in Wordpress Dashboard and gave that to the navigation menu.

It seems cool, but I need to get the link of each page to a `href`  element in my HTML document and after clicking change the URL on certain site... probably based on "slug".

I get my menu to variable in that way: 
`$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('main-navigation');`

and what exactly change or add in that code??

`<?php foreach($menu as $item) :?>
<a class="nav-link"  href="<?php the_permalink()?>">`

Does someone have a recommendation for that?

Thank you

Comment: <a class="nav-link"  href="<?php echo the_permalink()?>">

Comment: It does not execute anything...

Comment: Inspect the element and see if there is anything in the href

Comment: Yes, in Inspect element is href. but only for main page.. it will never change path

Comment: You need to do the link based on the $item object what does it contain?

Comment: when I debug my $menu .. each element contains Post Object Array with [url], [title] and etc ...

Comment: So what you need to do is use for the href="<?php echo $item->url or something like that